# Word for "quietly accumulating shares of stock by traders when the stock is at a lower price"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, vocabulary, collocation, technical

I'm looking for a word or expression that means "the act of quietly accumulating shares of stock by traders when the stock is at a lower price"?

Comment: Perhaps simply _[quiet accumulation](https://www.google.com/search?q="quiet+accumulation"+stock)_.

Comment: +1 for a nice question. Also, share what you found by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are referring to the practice of [averaging down](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/averagedown.asp):

This is an issue that usually  generates a lot of controversy among investors. Its application  highly depends on personal attitude to risk, experience and time investment horizon.

> The process of buying additional shares in a company at lower prices than you originally purchased. This brings the average price you've paid for all your shares down. Sometimes this is a good strategy, other times it's better to sell off a beaten down stock rather than buying more shares.

*In more general terms* any systematic buying of stocks, whatever the price level, is called [accumulation](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/accumulation.asp). The reason for accumulating shares depends on the buyers (long  term investment, trading, buy-out etc.).

> - An institutional investor's purchase of a large number of shares in a public company over an extended period of time.

Source: http://www.investopedia.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'd call it anything else but *[building a long position](http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Position+Building)*. Whether you've done it at a low price obviously can't be known until a later time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strategy used by investors, which is a part of their plan "buy low sell high." They either buy stocks of a company that are priced low or buy small cap stocks. However, I don't know of a term that means precisely what you are asking for.

But, what they are doing is a making a hoard or stockpile of small stocks, or you can say that they are hoarding or stockpiling stocks. The word "stockpile" is interesting because it includes the word "stock."